# Group polygons that touch and sum to ~1

Tags: r, polygon, sf

Looking for a solution in R to group polygons that (1) touch each other AND (2) sum to 1 (or as close to 1 as possible given the data). Understandably the data may not allow for perfect grouping, but I need to identify the greatest number of groupings that follow the above two rules.

If there are "left-over" polygons that don't quite sum to 1, they can simply be added into the nearest group. I understand that it may be a bit of a vague rule-set, but it's a real-world example so I seek some advice.

My spatial polygon object is in sf format.

[image]

Reproducible object (which I simplified a bit to reduce the size of the object):

```
structure(list(lprd_offtk = c(0.576595614111913, 0.470596431324882, 
0.313013556438852, 0.291847827347769, 0.246893506907835, 0.185238421883191, 
0.182961201600402, 0.0411038710600083), groups = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(249875.059541146, 
252012.035024516, 258685.257224514, 265376.684035709, 267738.088198923, 
275908.662976789, 281064.254433625, 279786.132666357, 272904.492138655, 
269709.525939596, 267311.523306026, 253821.487885182, 248648.505625685, 
232693.413456437, 219199.876598215, 213428.24184839, 218463.195819764, 
217154.422178502, 217499.473797489, 219490.715872187, 225421.030054584, 
227755.855655569, 234327.352083757, 239973.434780013, 246457.027469004, 
249875.059541146, -2494700.2653827, -2496056.45867386, -2489409.8295265, 
-2488249.04572909, -2492688.35003626, -2496804.08657781, -2503136.56846075, 
-2504891.76738967, -2504886.38095311, -2506784.91500093, -2511347.68966855, 
-2519728.1790659, -2529913.10281212, -2540847.16443872, -2539940.8520852, 
-2538048.37233691, -2532106.29000754, -2529129.92905356, -2517321.76768076, 
-2512825.00939204, -2512522.86185769, -2509495.51025011, -2508897.25719341, 
-2506040.65741496, -2500724.41107138, -2494700.2653827), .Dim = c(26L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(281064.254433625, 
284721.06606518, 279569.016927732, 282094.14898332, 281549.481661996, 
284157.142691013, 282305.321387715, 283204.573710021, 273726.267363972, 
269374.744023395, 267870.238560712, 266222.58758153, 256514.840665134, 
258248.422578011, 256043.736801008, 255083.684369923, 247588.829402245, 
242499.566458413, 239089.579903093, 235412.606442071, 232693.413456437, 
248648.505625685, 253821.487885182, 267311.523306026, 271048.972508793, 
279786.132666357, 281064.254433625, -2503136.56846075, -2516760.32569946, 
-2518872.10133995, -2520773.76435034, -2524275.20063014, -2530448.22436733, 
-2532136.38788482, -2537039.64229238, -2538755.21593081, -2538507.46831983, 
-2536692.85843521, -2538552.82296956, -2539217.17692106, -2543393.3685468, 
-2543839.44393153, -2548626.33101899, -2548550.97475263, -2551056.56970986, 
-2548313.03575587, -2548248.7328639, -2540847.16443872, -2529913.10281212, 
-2519728.1790659, -2511347.68966855, -2505846.46760906, -2504891.76738967, 
-2503136.56846075), .Dim = c(27L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(232693.413456437, 235412.606442071, 
239089.579903093, 244827.215235134, 242031.464922637, 231806.447551693, 
228328.092368238, 225160.026743837, 225673.702796975, 223775.699904158, 
222347.166277312, 218647.66260595, 214552.65515603, 204583.843831019, 
192032.247618289, 200080.060096766, 200277.787113699, 191486.447821016, 
189540.547330367, 188622.34734284, 191180.019984731, 191764.263346018, 
194439.83928237, 193200.560979109, 197259.461397278, 203059.868545647, 
205319.554316276, 210196.492259697, 209272.229830089, 213428.24184839, 
219199.876598215, 232693.413456437, -2540847.16443872, -2548248.7328639, 
-2548313.03575587, -2554139.64623601, -2562157.82691972, -2572652.06161707, 
-2580661.46857492, -2582586.73282374, -2590361.64630144, -2600768.83961439, 
-2601118.96791017, -2596549.23096386, -2595908.84828633, -2587558.31098132, 
-2582008.47163027, -2578878.15330717, -2576213.00214426, -2576060.33555871, 
-2573428.41342399, -2566314.3667436, -2565176.09049602, -2562132.22863948, 
-2562197.32229417, -2559373.61809678, -2555845.10698301, -2553173.01189052, 
-2554712.86185243, -2550544.36669981, -2545872.33950869, -2538048.37233691, 
-2539940.8520852, -2540847.16443872), .Dim = c(32L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
"POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(293014.518153712, 
302663.623878803, 299614.736129523, 299387.143977218, 300713.765833193, 
296012.630953997, 296414.646404753, 291613.202872935, 290101.086700019, 
288351.994932675, 280050.141744657, 276348.36159945, 268239.242818116, 
266664.696781647, 261329.775210368, 260803.076643104, 255043.118691357, 
256043.736801008, 258248.422578011, 256514.840665134, 266222.58758153, 
267870.238560712, 269719.998476136, 278115.141692842, 279027.238226489, 
277046.169367799, 278663.587566502, 278390.166162141, 282776.00453892, 
293014.518153712, -2545938.99223406, -2547984.25248741, -2552335.30469973, 
-2556748.93411025, -2557918.93443286, -2563255.41718524, -2568141.48940461, 
-2573873.67048764, -2580713.55216644, -2582358.27226944, -2575126.00563387, 
-2567008.30844017, -2561285.47027227, -2554370.63011131, -2552687.15762284, 
-2548859.05347352, -2548368.6934926, -2543839.44393153, -2543393.3685468, 
-2539217.17692106, -2538552.82296956, -2536692.85843521, -2538627.15944761, 
-2538204.23532964, -2539662.47951233, -2542253.48922496, -2543160.74876303, 
-2545303.54715771, -2547900.42101953, -2545938.99223406), .Dim = c(30L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(306327.164679465, 
312157.87829059, 315727.813056016, 322247.863289479, 324734.234123038, 
322280.899985046, 313282.956380406, 313182.865420436, 308893.020782966, 
297419.243993161, 296690.990207211, 294621.852014004, 291701.900610509, 
291614.741438732, 287419.223157528, 287044.692168127, 283344.246238729, 
282305.321387715, 284157.142691013, 281549.481661996, 282094.14898332, 
279695.910810639, 296955.864084469, 300889.267765777, 306327.164679465, 
-2508039.61053055, -2510727.11046957, -2509609.55377647, -2510558.39775827, 
-2513719.50300778, -2516967.49656351, -2518999.15235832, -2524753.05450383, 
-2529273.04419919, -2529592.16669518, -2525868.72839632, -2531644.56754877, 
-2533950.26964505, -2536931.8001659, -2537502.94552915, -2534657.51917214, 
-2536843.47016035, -2532136.38788482, -2530448.22436733, -2524275.20063014, 
-2520773.76435034, -2518693.05659809, -2515926.86985414, -2511082.96444285, 
-2508039.61053055), .Dim = c(25L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(242499.566458413, 247588.829402245, 
258286.862425668, 260803.076643104, 261329.775210368, 264273.044612322, 
258473.97206371, 259983.568923105, 255154.98928701, 256902.238131262, 
255753.861067199, 247571.580948403, 235663.721895586, 225742.204227351, 
225435.119550552, 228328.092368238, 231806.447551693, 242144.157713471, 
244827.215235134, 242499.566458413, -2551056.56970986, -2548550.97475263, 
-2548187.135643, -2548859.05347352, -2552687.15762284, -2554049.32231806, 
-2560167.55876203, -2568074.91322253, -2577506.8627014, -2589015.02513639, 
-2590721.649419, -2587110.19199153, -2585872.89272702, -2588552.69485312, 
-2582111.24615956, -2580661.46857492, -2572652.06161707, -2561940.41176137, 
-2554139.64623601, -2551056.56970986), .Dim = c(20L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
"POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(288351.994932675, 
287495.305756137, 276680.392697904, 270919.365058707, 269340.771068311, 
265346.889957803, 255230.477628228, 254108.340437253, 256902.238131262, 
255154.98928701, 259983.568923105, 258651.712140395, 263994.051303531, 
264273.044612322, 267106.535022276, 268239.242818116, 276348.36159945, 
280050.141744657, 288351.994932675, -2582358.27226944, -2585779.41018566, 
-2591654.24876776, -2591005.29640292, -2594986.78395064, -2598683.40780428, 
-2605133.21307845, -2593026.46124507, -2589015.02513639, -2577506.8627014, 
-2568074.91322253, -2559477.35553307, -2555735.53509041, -2554049.32231806, 
-2554955.3087209, -2561285.47027227, -2567008.30844017, -2575126.00563387, 
-2582358.27226944), .Dim = c(19L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(283344.246238729, 287308.169406312, 
287085.111647096, 289727.343964804, 290109.939547828, 292235.963342529, 
291094.720439021, 293014.518153712, 288473.592209144, 284340.809701151, 
278585.400462918, 278663.587566502, 277046.169367799, 279027.238226489, 
278150.997236807, 283344.246238729, -2536843.47016035, -2534707.65334712, 
-2537145.99703628, -2537864.30653648, -2540981.9151418, -2541866.91487573, 
-2544021.83441239, -2545938.99223406, -2546010.51264318, -2548264.35775681, 
-2545525.57453531, -2543160.74876303, -2542253.48922496, -2539662.47951233, 
-2537406.872217, -2536843.47016035), .Dim = c(16L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
"POLYGON", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, precision = 0, crs = structure(list(
    input = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"unknown\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"unknown\",\n        DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8901]]],\n    CONVERSION[\"unknown\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",27,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",1,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), bbox = structure(c(xmin = 188622.34734284, ymin = -2605133.21307845, 
xmax = 324734.234123038, ymax = -2488249.04572909), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(lprd_offtk = NA_integer_, 
groups = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Share reproducible data otherwise there is no chance that somebody will help you

Comment: Thanks, I've added some data.

Comment: "close to 1 as possible given the data" is the difficult bit. I suspect this has similar complexity to something like the travelling salesperson problem, where the best solution is computationally very expensive to find.

Comment: It would be useful to see what you've tried already. Do you know this is essentially a graph theory problem? Have you built the connectivity graph and maybe converted to the `igraph` package format and looked at methods there/

Comment: I started by working through this example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310462/cluster-geometries-that-touch-each-other?noredirect=1&lq=1. Which allowed me to group shared boundaries. But I've not made any in-roads into how to incorporate the value~1 parameter.

Comment: It would be prudent to conceptualize your problem so that the outcome is clearer. I often make students work through ideas like this by hand so they start realizing what they are asking. You are, in reality, looking at a spatial optimization problem. For instance, how are you going to deal with polygons that are chosen for more than one summed cluster? How should direction of neighbors be addressed, always clockwise, and does this create a systematic bias in the outcome? Do you want to consider 2nd order contingency of a solution is not found? I know that this seem simple but, no so much.

Comment: This looks like a standard problem - for example how to group small electoral units with varying populations into larger connected units with approximately the same populations. I suspect there's heuristic approaches, like pick a seed, grow it, pick a new one, then do swaps or additions/subs etc using something like simulated annealing until you find a "solution" based on some optimisation function. But its unlikely to find the true best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we have indicated all of the issues you could try some clustering approaches using optimizations such as Simulated Annealing. Here is a quick worked example using Max-p Simulated Annealing. The use of `queen_weights` is defining first order neighbors (those that touch) and the optimization target is 10% of the population which would be similar to your "sum to 1 target". Keep in mind that this clustering approach uses simulated annealing so, changes in the heating parameter can result in very different solutions.

```
library(sf)
library(rgeoda)

guerry <- st_read(system.file("extdata", "Guerry.shp", 
                  package = "rgeoda"))
  guerry <- guerry[c('Crm_prs','Crm_prp','Pop1831')]

ijw <- queen_weights(guerry)
  mpc <- maxp_sa(ijw, guerry, guerry['Pop1831'], 3236.67, 
                 cooling_rate=0.85, sa_maxit=1)
    guerry$clust <- mpc$Clusters
      plot(guerry["clust"])
```

Here we check the solution(s)

```
for(i in sort(unique(guerry$clust))) {
  cat("sum of cluster", i, sum(guerry[guerry$clust == i,]$Pop1831),
      "with target of 3236.67",  "\n")
}
```

[image: example cluster solution]

Now, lets look at your data (p sf polygon object was created from the structure output in the original post).

```
ijw <- queen_weights(p)
  mpc <- maxp_sa(ijw, p, p["lprd_offtk"], 1, 
                 cooling_rate=0.85, sa_maxit=1)
    p$clust <- mpc$Clusters
      plot(p["clust"])
```

Here we can check how close to target sum we get (in my run it was 2 cluster solutions with 1.261058 and 1.047192).

```
for(i in sort(unique(p$clust))) {
  cat("sum of cluster", i, sum(p[p$clust == i,]$lprd_offtk),
      "with target of 1",  "\n")
}
```

[image: your data cluster solution]

Comment: Great solution, working well for my use case. Appreciate the explanation and response. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to add some constraint? For example dont cluster if the difference of some attribute between two adjacent areas are more than something?

Comment: @BERA you would have to implement a multi-objective optimization. Given the complexity of MO problems, computational efficiency is a consideration. A great approach is ILP, showing considerable efficiency over simulated annealing. I would reccomend taking a look at the `prioritizer` package for interger linear programming based optimization solutions.