# Division of polygon into irregular shape and varying area of polygons

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have a major polygon showing in the following image and **its area is 264387.097089999995660 hectare**  (area can be in any unit, mostly in hectare),

[image: this is major polygon with known area]

I want to divide this polygon into any numbers of sub polygon (like 20 sub-polygon, 329 sub-polygon, more or less in number). e.g., showing following image, I divide it into 20 sub-polygon but the area of all 20 sub-polygon is equal.
[image]

I have area of all 20 sub-polygon e.g., ( 2900312, 7100312, 4900312, 8500456, and so on)hectare.

I want to divide this major polygon into any number of irregular sub polygon according to the given area not in equal. How can I divide it?

I am trying to do it in QGIS using polygon divider plugin, also in ArcGIS. Also trying in PostGIS using K-mean Cluster function but didn't get desired result.

Comment: There are literally an *infinite* number of ways to do this.

Comment: Random points in polygon, than voronoi polygons. For othet solutions,  please add more information

Comment: @Vince please provide me any specific solution for my problem.

Comment: GIS SE is a problem-solving site. You haven't presented one problem, but an infinite number of them. You need to chose how you intend to resolve the task, make an attempt, encounter a problem, and provide details of the problem before the Question is sufficiently focused for GIS SE.

Answer (score 2):

[ST_Subdivide](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html) it:

> Divides geometry into parts using rectilinear lines, until each part
> can be represented using no more than max_vertices

```
select st_subdivide(geometry, 200) as geom
from "your_table"
```

[image]

Comment: can we give area for creation of sub-polygon as input?

Comment: To this tool, no

Comment: please tell me any other tool or solution where I get somehow solution of my problem, if you can.

Comment: I dont know, this problem is very difficult. This is an example of solving a similar one using R: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417679/group-polygons-that-touch-and-sum-to-1